# Cannot Connect to Oracle in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle in a 32-bit Console Application. I am getting the following erorr. The code (with the exception of host, username, and password change) is below. It is a simple two function project.

Any help will be appreciated.

I am using C# in Visual Studion 2010 Premium and Oracle 10g. I can connect to the database with Oracle SQL Developer with the information set in the connection string.

---

---------------ToString--------------------------
--Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException     at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, Oracle
Connection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.GetConnection() in c:\users\maholt\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 61

### ---------------Message---------------------------

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static OracleConnection conn;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OracleConnection connC = GetConnection();

            conn = connC;
            simpleQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        }

        public static void simpleQuery()
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select count(*) as total from console.client");

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(reader["total"]));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public static OracleConnection GetConnection()
        {
            Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection rtn = null;
            try
            {
                string connstr = "Data Source=//10.10.10.10:1521/PRD2_OLTP;User Id=user; Password=pass;";

                rtn = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connstr);

                if (rtn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    rtn.Open();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("---------------ToString--------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("--" + ee.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("---------------Message---------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("--" + ee.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            }

            return (rtn);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception message?  You have a header for it but don't seem to have included the text.  Is the message blank?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer uses effectively JDBC connection... so it is not really comparable with what happens in .NET :-(

Regarding the Oracle versus .NET version compatibility - I found this rather problematic esp. since the clients don't have always the option to update according to Oracle roadmap...

After researching some I switched to using the [Devart components](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) - support everything from Oracle 7.3 up to 11gR2  in .NET 2 up with 32 and 64 bit and come with a "direct-mode option" which means if need be I can run my app without any Oracle client being installed on the machine... not affiliated, just a happy customer...

Answer (score 0):

First - Oracle doesn't support 10g with .net 4.0.  You must use 11.2.0.2 or higher to be compliant with Oracle's supported versions.

Second - The problem is you probably don't have ODP.Net installed correctly.  This can mean it isn't installed, it was installed to a second instance, or it failed to copy on or more files during installation.

I have some blog posts about these items along with a link to some connection testing applications I wrote.  Feel free to use them.

https://tsells.wordpress.com/category/oracle/